How to write test cases to validate if fees is paid?
I'm working on writing test cases for an extrinsic that conditionally bypasses transaction fees based on specific conditions. I need to verify whether the fees are paid or not for a given call. My current approach involves checking the balance of the caller both before and after executing the extrinsic.
In my test case, I compare the caller's balance before and after the call. Ideally, the balance should differ if the fee is paid. However, in my tests, the balance remains the same, which raises the question: Is this a valid approach to check whether the fee was deducted?
Is there a more reliable way to verify fee payment or fee bypass for an extrinsic? Should I be using a different strategy to test this scenario?
Note: I'm aware of the process where we can check the Pays::No events. But I need of check if actually fees is paid or not, because these events (Pays::No or Pays::Yes) we return from our extrinsic.

Follow the transaction-payment mock setup.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/868a36bd186f3ef9535ebf7deceac1b2fab19fcb/substrate/frame/transaction-payment/src/mock.rs#L1

And I think this test is exactly what you want.

https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/868a36bd186f3ef9535ebf7deceac1b2fab19fcb/substrate/frame/transaction-payment/src/tests.rs#L132

